# Why I can't load images from json file with webpack-5?

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, webpack, webpack-5

When I use the IMG tag in the html, it works just fine. But, when I'm trying to generate some HTML with an image URL (which is from the JSON file) in the Javascript and insert it, the images are being inserted, but not with the hash, and also the desired image is not being generated in the image folder. Webpack is just skipping it. I tried hard, but couldn't find a way. Please help me! I'm frustrated.

Here is my json data:

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": "./images/avatars/image-alex.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": "./images/avatars/image-tom.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my Webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    port: 2222,
    hot: false,
    open: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "images/[name].[hash].[ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "data/[name].[hash].[ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Here is my javascript:

```
import rawJson from "../json/data.json";
const containerEl = document.querySelector(".all-persons-container");

const dataJson = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(rawJson);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

let allPersons = await dataJson().then((data) => {
  return data.persons;
});

const img = allPersons[0].image;
console.log(img);

const insert = async () => {
  const markup = `
      <img
        src="${img}"
      />
    `;

  containerEl.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", markup);
};

insert();
```

I also attached my project tree:[Preject tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pZX2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source image file must be imported or required in JavaScript:

```js
import img from "./images/avatars/image-alex.png";
// OR
const img = require("./images/avatars/image-alex.png");

console.log(img); // => output image file
```

The Webpack parses JS code and extracts required images at "server side" and the variable `img` will contains already processed output filename of image.

But in runtime it is impossible, the Browser don't know where is your source image.

Comment: First, I can't use import, because I have hundreds of URLs from JSON. 

I tried your second suggestion. When I do like this it works: 
const img = require("./images/avatars/image-alex.png");

But, when I do like this it doesn't work:
const img = require(allPersons[0].image);

instead, it shows this error: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

In other words, if I use a hardcoded URL, it works, but if I get the URL from the JSON, it doesn't. That's the problem now. :(

Comment: Note: `const img = require("./images/avatars/image-alex.png");` is processed at server side, it work. But `const img = require(allPersons[0].image);` will be called at runtime in your browser, it don't work. That's right, there is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
Based in the **biodiscus** answer, my solution (for time reasons) was converted the .json file into a .js file and add the require hardcode URL

```
    //original Json file
    {
      "persons": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "image": "./images/avatars/image-alex.png"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "image": "./images/avatars/image-tom.png"
        }
      ]
    }

    //js converted file
    export default {
      "persons": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "image": require("./images/avatars/image-alex.png")
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "image": require("./images/avatars/image-tom.png")
        }
      ]
    }
```

---

You can use regex expression in vscode to replace all the url strings into require:
**[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbxPQ.png)
[Replace regex image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdJMc.png)**